# Bitrix исчезла панель администратора

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

В "Битрикс Управление сайтом" исчезла панель администратора. Ничего не менял, не делал, просто открыл на следующий день страницу - панели нет!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было перейти по ссылке /bitrix/admin/index.php и залогиниться.